# Workflow rule for Closedate

Tags: workflow

Hi I need a work flow that close date(Opportunity) should be populated only on creation. Not when the record is updated.

Comment: This functionality is achieved through `Validation Rule`...

Comment: can you give me validation rule

Answer (score 3):

Create a workflow with evaluation criteria set to **Evaluate the rule when a record is created** and add an field update action to update close date field.

Comment: @Frodo  I used this rule IsClosed equals TRUE , and field update is Today(), but its showing only previous date.

Comment: What is the stage you are setting?? When you are creating the record. `IsClosed` field is only true when stage is either **closed won** or **closed lost**